# Create dictionary where values are keys transformed to strings

Tags: python, dictionary, networkx

`G` is a graph object and `sorted(G)` returns a list of nodes:

```
[0,1,2...1860]
```

I need to rename those nodes mapping from a dictionary, like so:

```
mapping = {0: "0_cereb", 1: "1_cereb", 2: "2_cereb",..., 1860: "1860_cereb"}
```

And then I can apply dict to a method that relabels my graph:

```
import networkx as nx
Gnew = nx.relabel_nodes(G, mapping)
```

and `sorted(Gnew)`returns:

```
[0_cereb, 2_cereb, ..., 1860_cereb]
```

---

How do I create this `mapping` `dict`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a dictionary comprehension to create the dictionary, and use string formatting to convert the numbers to the corresponding strings.

```
mapping = {x: f'{x}_cereb' for x in G}
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer would be dict comprehension

```
mapping = {k: f"{k}_cereb" for k in sorted(G)}
```

will run through list and create key value pairs